# How to resolve TypeScript error "Type 'Dayjs' is missing properties from type 'Date'" when using Day.js with Material-UI DatePicker?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, datepicker, dayjs

I'm trying to use Day.js with Material-UI's `DatePicker` component in my React project. However, when I set the `minDate` and `maxDate` properties to Day.js objects, I get a TypeScript error:

```
Type 'Dayjs' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 35 more.
```

I understand that `DatePicker` expects `minDate` and `maxDate` to be of type `Date`, but Day.js returns a `Dayjs` object.

Code:

```js
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import dayjs from "dayjs";

interface DatepickerProperties {
  label: string;
  onChange: (value: Date | null) => void;
  disablePast?: boolean;
}

function Datepicker({
  label,
  onChange,
  disablePast = false,
}: DatepickerProperties) {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        disablePast={disablePast}
        label={label}
        onChange={onChange}
        minDate={dayjs()}
        maxDate={dayjs("9999-12-31")}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
  );
}
```

**Expected Behavior:**
I expect the `DatePicker` component to accept `minDate` and `maxDate` as Day.js objects without any TypeScript errors.

**Actual Behavior:**
I'm getting the TypeScript error mentioned above when using Day.js objects for `minDate` and `maxDate`.

**What I've tried:**
I've attempted to convert the Day.js object to a Date object using `toDate()`, but this cause a bunch of another errors:

```
AdapterDayjs.js:384 Uncaught TypeError: value.isAfter is not a function
    at AdapterDayjs.isAfterDay (AdapterDayjs.js:384:22)
    at getDefaultReferenceDate (getDefaultReferenceDate.js:53:38)
    at Object.getInitialReferenceValue (valueManagers.js:21:12)
    at useFieldState.js:58:41
    at mountState (react-dom.development.js:16986:20)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17699:16)
    at Object.useState (react.development.js:1622:21)
    at useFieldState (useFieldState.js:48:35)
    at useField (useField.js:29:7)
    at useDateField (useDateField.js:29:10)
```

How can I properly resolve the TypeScript error(s)?

Comment: Remember to put code, including error logs, in code fences. It's not a plain text paragraph quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good, but I think you are passing the `DatepickerProperties` interface incorrectly.

If you want to use Dayjs objects for date manipulation, you should change the type of the `onChange` callback from `Date` to `Dayjs`. This way, you can avoid converting between Date and Dayjs objects and keep your code consistent.

For example, you can try this:

```
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from "dayjs";

interface DatepickerProperties {
  label: string;
  onChange: (value: Dayjs | null) => void;
  disablePast?: boolean;
}
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-surf-9y6gxx?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: Great that fixed my error.

Comment: I'm glad you fixed the error. - @Dawid

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer, I had no idea this was causing my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend props from `DatePickerProps<Dayjs>`.
Example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import {
  DatePicker as MUIDatePicker,
  DatePickerProps,
} from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { Dayjs } from "dayjs";

type TDatePickerProps = DatePickerProps<Dayjs> & {
  errorMessage?: string;
};

const DatePicker: React.FC<TDatePickerProps> = ({
  sx,
  errorMessage,
  ...otherProps
}) => (
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <MUIDatePicker
      {...otherProps}
      slotProps={{
        textField: {
          error: !!errorMessage,
          helperText: errorMessage,
          fullWidth: true,
          size: "small",
          sx: {
            "& .MuiFormHelperText-root": { marginLeft: "3px" },
            ...sx,
          },
        },
      }}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
);

export default DatePicker;
```

Answer (score 0):

### **Use `.toDate()`**

While the other answers may have relevance in other contexts, `dayjs` does have a function to convert output to a regular Date object. I had similar error to OP and this cleared it up.

**Example:**
`dayjs('2019-01-25').toDate()`

https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/as-javascript-date